# assign port number to localhost

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, localhost

I have an URL `http://localhost/Login.aspx` in my application which is not working:

```
<a href='http://localhost/Login.aspx'>Login</a>
```

But it works on:

```
<a href='http://localhost:51807/Login.aspx'>Login</a>
```

### Question is:

How can I assign the port number `51807` to the URL `http://localhost/Login.aspx` when user click on **Login** `<a href='http://localhost/Login.aspx'>Login</a>`?

Comment: Why you are using `http://localhost` in your link?

Comment: as link is on my local machine.

Comment: _<a href='~/Login.aspx'>Login</a>_ ?

Comment: url changes to *http://localhost:51807/~/Login.aspx* and says to page found.

Comment: Sorry I am not so well versed in ASP.NET to understand what is your problem. Hope this search could help you in some way https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20reference%20root%20of%20the%20site%20in%20asp.net&qs=n&sk=&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US

Comment: @Steve thanks for your search but its not adding port number in the URL.

Comment: `/Login.aspx` should work. If you're using Razor, you can create links direct to actions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relativ Link

```
<a href='./Login.aspx'>Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The port number is generated by visual studio during project creation to avoid port conflict when developing/debuging multiple web application at the same time. This temporary port will not affect you deployment in production

Regarding you issue, consider using `<asp:HyperLink>` to generate links instead of using plain html `<a>` tag, e.g.:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx">Login</asp:HyperLink>
```

ASP.NET will transform the `~` in the url to the actual root path of the web application, make sure the link always relative to the root path.

e.g. in your case `http://localhost:51807/Login.aspx`

or in production `http://some.domain/Login.aspx` in a production,

or if your web application is deployed as a virtual application `http://some.domain/virtualapp/Login.aspx`